# SPARQL query and distinct count

Tags: count, sparql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT ?tag WHERE {
  ?r ns9:taggedWithTag ?tagresource.
  ?tagresource ns9:name ?tag
}
LIMIT 5000
```

and the results are:

```sql
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abd
ads
anb
```

I want to get somthing like:

```sql
tag | count
-----------------
abc     7
abd     1
ads     1
anb     1
```

I have tried it with `count(*)` and `count(?tag)`, but than I get the error message `"Variable or "*" expected."` Can someone tell me, how to make it right?

Comment: Core SPARQL doesn't have aggregates like COUNT. Which SPARQL extension you're working with?

Comment: I think, i'm using the core :(

Comment: @laalto Just as a note, the latest version of SPARQL, version 1.1, from 2013, *does* include aggregates.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're using Java and Jena's ARQ, you can use [ARQ's extensions for aggregates](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/group-by.html). Your query would look something like:

```sql
SELECT ?tag (count(distinct ?tag) as ?count)
WHERE {
    ?r ns9:taggedWithTag ?tagresource.
    ?tagresource ns9:name ?tag
}
LIMIT 5000
```

The [original SPARQL specification from 2008](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) didn't include aggregates, but [the current version, 1.1, from 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) does.

Comment: it doesn't but aggregates are getting added to SPARQL 1.1 and they are widely implemented (via different extensions, as noted)

Answer (score 37):

Using COUNT(), MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), AVG() with GROUP BY can produce summary values for groups of triples.  Note, these patterns might be specific to SPARQL 1.1.

For example, this one can sum the ?value for each ?category,

```sql
SELECT ?category (SUM(?value) as ?valueSum)
WHERE
{
  ?s ?category ?value .
}
GROUP BY ?category
```

This one can count the number of uses for predicate ?p,

```sql
SELECT ?p (COUNT(?p) as ?pCount)
WHERE
{
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
GROUP BY ?p
```

These examples are inspired by material from Bob DuCharme (2011), "Learning SPARQL". O’Reilly Media, Sebastopol, CA, USA; see http://www.learningsparql.com/

**To avoid the error "Bad aggregate" upon using GROUP BY**:

1. The grouping variables should match ; (?category in the first example)
2. The rest of the variables in the SELECT should each result into one value ; (SUM(?value) as ?valueSum) in the first example.