# SPARQL: Count how often an object property is used

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I have an RDF graph and I want to count how many times the [skos:broader](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#semantic-relations) object property is actually used. Is there a simple (and ideally efficient) SPARQL query I can use for that?

Comment: And what did you try? Did you look at aggregate functions in SPARQL? The obvious query would be `SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt) {?s skos:broader ?o }` , but I don't know what you haven't be able to write this simple query by yourself. Efficiency is limited by the triple store, clearly a `pso` index could be used + counting

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed answer my question! To be honest, I was writing a much more complex `COUNT` query that did not run efficiently and missed the obvious one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPARQL query and distinct count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223472/sparql-query-and-distinct-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially simple answer:

```sql
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt)
  WHERE { ?s skos:broader ?o }
```