# Count column values in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, anzograph, sparql-generate

I am writing a query in SPARQL for a knowledge graph.
I have a column having Country and names of countries repeating.
For example: Japan, India, US, India, India, US, US, Romania etc. and so on.

I need to write a SPARQL query that gives me the count of each country in that column.
Example: Japan 1, India 3, US 3 etc. and so on.

```
SELECT ?countryName COUNT(?CountryName)
WHERE
{
...
}
GROUP BY ?countryName
HAVING (?countryName = "Germany")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "column"? As the result of a SPARQL query? Also, what does not work with your current query (besides the invalid syntax of course)?

Comment: it should be `SELECT ?countryName (COUNT(*) AS ?cnt)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPARQL query and distinct count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223472/sparql-query-and-distinct-count)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ?countryName COUNT(*) AS ?count
WHERE 
{ ?iri a OBJECT . 
?iri rdfs:label ?countryName . 
} 
GROUP BY ?countryName
```

Keep in mind that you will need to replace OBJECT with the entity type, and I have assumed you are using the `rdfs:label` predicate for the labels.